# Is alarm(unsigned int second) function thread_safe?

Tags: c, linux

With `alarm` function, I want to implement UDP retransmission. Is this function thread safe? Will it work under multi-threaded environment.

Comment: Have you referred to the docs?

Comment: Please add tags - what language?

Answer (score 3):

Calling `alarm()` in a thread will not reset pending signals, so you probably don't want to call it *in* a thread. You'd only want to call it within the parent no matter what language you are using if the underlying functionality is pthreads.

You'd probably be better off making provisions in a structure shared with the threads to re-send data as needed, or poke all (or some) running threads to resend upon servicing the signal in the parent.

I can't think of an implementation where calling it within a thread would be a good idea, so no - I wouldn't use it that way.

Comment: My thinking is that a thread which takes responsible for send data specially.And the retransmittion algorithm based on stevens's UNIX NetWwork programming vol1 chapter22.According to the book, it adopts alarm() function.

Comment: But I know alarm() function without deep understanding.As a timer, it may be improper.Could you give me some tips about timer which could diplace it.

Comment: @lojunren It adopts `alarm()` _within_ a thread specifically to poke others for retransmission?

Comment: NO,It is just for pedagogical use. And it doesn't consider the multi-thread situation.I wanna make it work under multi-thread envirnoment.

Comment: Do you have some example code (even unfinished) you could add to your question? You would definitely need another clock source and means to lapse independently in each thread if you're doing what I think you're doing, but I can't quite be sure without seeing the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

alarm() function is not thread safe.

Because it is process level. You can't control which thread should receive the signal once timer triggers. So at the time of signal arrival, another thread may be running. Sometimes it may crash you program with SIG_SEGV.

Comment: Actually it should be safe. The relevant concern with alarm() itself as the OP asked would be whether the timer value could become corrupted from parallel calls in separate threads, but as it's usually a system call that should not occur and the latest interval will always be in play.

The potential problem as mentioned in other answers comes from handling signals safely in a multithreaded environment, but that's a separate issue and concern. If alarm() is used for a watchdog timer and the behaviour of the signal handler is to call exit(), there need not be any problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/alarm.html) `alarm` is "process-level" and only the last call is active... it uses the SIGNAL model and sends an async SIGALARAM to the process... whether the called signal handler is threadsafe depends on your implementation...